# Match items accross two rows and two columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to write a formula / conditional formatting to match two items within the same column and then confirm that the next row item has a match within that column. If a match is detected then preferably highlight that row.

```
For example:
A B C 
1 x 5
3 y 7
2 z 9
1 x 9
2 y 9
```

In column A there are several matches. A1, A4, and A3, A5 however only B1 and B4 match as a second condition so only rows 1 and 4 should be highlighted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select column A:C and use conditional formatting rule:

```
=COUNTIFS($A:A,$A1,$B:B,$B1)>1
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I now wish to add an additional column with binary inputs say A or B only (text). I need a match to only be triggered if the values in the third column are different ie A in row 1 and B in row 4

Regards

Comment: Sounds like a new question to me. @Aaron. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

**Steps:**

1. Set this formula to column D `=A2 & "_" & B2`
2. Select the values in column D and go to Home:

   1. Styles
   2. Conditional Formatting
   3. Highlight Cells Rules
   4. Duplicate Values

**Results:**

[image]